What are the white square artifacts in the corners of KDE gui elements?
I run Ubuntu Studio 24.04, with X11 and an nVidia GTX 1080Ti graphics card.
The desktop is the default KDE Plasma that came with the installation.
In selected menus, buttons, text-input fields and sliders, there are these thin white square-ish artifacts in the corners, and it's somewhat annoying.
Does anyone know where they come from, or if they can be removed?
Edit: It seems to only occur if I select the theme "Oxygen", but still, this cannot be meant to be part of the theme?


The Oxygen theme was created in KDE Plasma 4 and was included in Plasma 5 mostly for nostalgia and backward compatibility sake. It hasn't really been maintained since.
This is very much an upstream issue with KDE. You'll notice the same issue if you were to install Kubuntu, so this is very much not an Ubuntu Studio issue.
